# Understanding Word Embeddings

Tags: neural-network, word2vec, word-embeddings

Can someone direct me to research papers that have tried to understand word embeddings?

Answer (score 1):

The original papers written by Thomas Mikolov are [word2vec](http://web2.cs.columbia.edu/~blei/seminar/2016_discrete_data/readings/MikolovSutskeverChenCorradoDean2013.pdf) and [doc2vec](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.4053v2.pdf).

[Lecture notes](http://cs224d.stanford.edu/lecture_notes/LectureNotes1.pdf) given by Richard Socher is simple to understand.

[word2vec explained](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.3722.pdf) gives an intuition how the negative sampling in word embedding works. Not the whole algorithm though.

Nevertheless, there are implementations in various languages and libraries explaining how it works in their docs.

Python - [gensim](https://rare-technologies.com/making-sense-of-word2vec/), [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/word2vec/)

java - [deeplearning4j](https://deeplearning4j.org/word2vec)

Comment: thanks but after the original papers...do you know if there were any other research papers that tried it.

Comment: @devc: Glove tries to generate word embeddings too, but in a different approach. https://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/glove.pdf

Comment: See also https://research.fb.com/fasttext/

Answer (score 0):

I found this [google course](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/embeddings/obtaining-embeddings?hl=en) also helpful for understanding the principle concept of embeddings, as they also use videos to explain it visually.